# how to add javascript function to html tag?

Tags: javascript, html, function

Just curious, and want to know. Can I add a javascript function to certain html tag? In example, if I have div tag like this:

```
<div id="example">Hello!</div>
```

and want to add function that alert the value inside of every div like:

```
function divFunction(){
     alert(/*some div content*/);
}
```

so, it can be executed like:

```
<div id="example">Hello!</div>
<script>
     document.getElementById("example").divFunction();
</script>
```

The point of my question is to add some new attribute or function to a certain tags. Like if there is:

```
document.getElementById("example").innerHTML;
```

can it be:

```
document.getElementById("example").newAttribute;
```

What makes me curious because jQuery can done something like this:

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html" );
```

Comment: What do you mean by "adding a function to html tag"? What is the effect, if you click on the div the function calls ?

Comment: Sure, you can add a JavaScript function to a `script` tag. You can also mess with elements' prototypes, but I suppose that is not what you're asking. Or is it? The code looks like you'd like to monkey patch native HTML elements ..?

Comment: @Teemu This made me LOL.. Really top answer (based on the question) :D

Comment: @Maverick what I mean is to add function or attribute to a tag. in example there is `document.getElementById("example").innerHTML`, it makes me curious if is it possible `document.getElementById("example").newAttribute` can be done, because jQuery can do something like `$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html" );`.

Comment: @user2265229 No, because what you are doing there is calling the functions inherited by $(). You would have to write your on function (class) and have functions called on it. Example: `Myselector('example')` this will have the same result as `document.getElementById` then in `Myselector ` class add functions like `newAttribute`, `doSomething` etc... and then call it on your class `Myselector('example').newAttribute('foo');`

Comment: @Maverick thanks. That answer what I mean.

Comment: If you want I will write it and give you an example so you can mark it as solved. But edit your question add what you explained to me

Comment: @Maverick done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't possible because $ (jQuery) and document are defined objects that have there in built functions.

Because when you use `.` you call an object member.

`Foo.bar()` - Calling function `bar()` defined **inside** and object `Foo`.

So you would have to make your class/selector.

Here is a simple example:

```js
class select {
 constructor(selector) {
   this._element = document.getElementById(selector);
  }
  
  // Functions
  
  colorMe() {
   this._element.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }

  moveMe(x) {
    this._element.style.marginTop = x;
  }
}

var elem = new select("example");

elem.colorMe();
elem.moveMe("50px");
```

```html
<div id="example">
  This is an example
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

DOM elements are like javascript objects with certain properties, so you could add a new property to, in your case a new function.

Here's an example:

```js
var element = document.querySelector('#example');

function bindToNode(node, name, fn) {
  node[name] = fn.bind(node);
}

bindToNode(element, 'logValue', function() {
  console.log(this.textContent);
});

element.logValue();
```

```html
<div id="example">
  Hello!
</div>
```

But you shouldn't mess arround with DOM elements, a better way would be to wrap the elements like jQuery does.

Comment: i think this answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little weird and inadvisable, but it's possible.

```js
tag=document.querySelector('#myTag')
tag.test=tag=>{tag.innerText=tag.id};
tag.test(tag);
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="myTag"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add events to the DOM elements. Read this page https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_events.asp for more information or see a small example below

```js
function divFunction(){
     alert(document.getElementById("example").innerText);
}
```

```html
<div id="example" onclick="divFunction()">Hello!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the html element to your javascript function. Add an element argument in your function definition.

```
function divFunction(el){
     alert(el.innerHTML);
}
```

And use `getElementById` to reference the element to use as an argument.

```
<div id="example">Hello!</div>
<script>
     divFunction(document.getElementById("example"));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible without the use of any library.

I use it to validate the content of a  modal element saved in another file

This is *myModal.html*

```
<div id="myModal"... >
  some content
</div>

<script type="module">
  document.getElementById("myModal").validate = function() {
    console.log("validating");
    //some controls and DOM manipulations
    return true;
  };
</script>
```

In the other file *mainPage* (it could be a .cshtml or a .php page) i'm including *myModal.html*.

I can access the function because it's a div's function:

This is *MainPage.* :

```
<script type="module">
   let theModal = document.getElementById("myModal");
   let isValid = theModal.validate();
</script>
```

In this way the function is "portable" with the div and it's in the same file (no more copy and paste)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with custom-elements [[1]](https://javascript.info/custom-elements) [[2]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements)

1. create custom-element
2. add method to custom-element class
3. you can call the method

```js
export class CustomElementInput extends HTMLElement {

  log(){
    alert("log")
  }

  // you can even overwrite methods like so
  remove(){
    alert("removing this node")
    super.remove()
  }
}

customElements.define("custom-element-input", CustomElementInput)

// somewhere else...
// in your HTML something like:
// <custom-element-input></custom-element-input> 

const el = document.querySelector("custom-element-input")
el.log() // creates alert()
```

:)